# How does editing variable inside a class function works?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I stumbled upon this code that is supposed to remove the last element of a linked list.
I don't understand how by modifying a local variable we are modifying a class attribute:

```
class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }
  removeLast() {
    if (!this.head) {
      return;
    }

    if (!this.head.next) {
      this.head = null;
      return;
    }

    let previous = this.head;
    let node = this.head.next;
    while (node.next) {
      previous = node;
      node = node.next;
    }
    previous.next = null;
  }
}
```

Any explanation or link to better understand the subject ?
Thank you.

Comment: All the local variables in the code seem to refer to an object, hence you can modify the properties of the objects via the references stored in those local variables.

Comment: Thank you I found this link [link](https://javascript.info/object-copy) that explains what you are saying in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in your question modifies the object references.

Unlike primitive values, two variables can refer to the same object. As a result, modifying the object using any of the object reference, will modify the actual object and the changes will be reflected in all the object references.

**Example:**

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
const obj = { name: 'John' };
const obj2 = obj;

obj2.name = 'Mike';

console.log(obj);
```

In the above code example, `obj2.name` was changed but when `obj` was logged in the last line, value of the `name` property is changed to "Mike". This is because both `obj` and `obj2` point to the **same exact object in memory**.

To understand the code in your question, you need to keep the above code example in mind and understand how it works.

Following are the steps that explain how `removeLast()` method works:

1. Check if list is empty. If it is, return from the function because there is nothing to remove.

   ```
   if (!this.head) {
      return;
   }
   ```
2. If there's only one node in the linked list, make `head` point to `null` and then return from the function.

   ```
   if (!this.head.next) {
      this.head = null;
      return;
   }
   ```
3. Now, we need to traverse the linked list to reach the second last node in the linked list. When we have reached the second last node, we can point the `next` of the second last node to `null`. This will remove any reference to the last node.

   ```
   // create a temporary pointer to the first node 
   // in the linked list       
   let previous = this.head;

   // create a temporary pointer to the second node
   // in the linkedlist. "this.head.next" could be "null"
   // if there's only 1 node in the linkedlist 
   let node = this.head.next;

   // traverse the linkedlist until "node.next" is not "null"
   while (node.next) { 
      // point "previous" to the node that is pointed
      // to by "node" variable
      previous = node;

      // update "node" variable to point the node that
      // is next to the node that is currently pointed to by "node"
      // variable
      node = node.next;
   }
   ```
4. After the 3rd step, `previous` will point to the second last node in the linked list. Finally, the `next` of the second last node is set to `null`. Doing this will remove the last node.

   ```
   previous.next = null;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the precision about object references, that's what I was missing.